# How to create PHP script

Tags: php

I am trying to create simple HTML form/PHP script from were user can input info and what i want to do is just to appear on screen bellow if it was successful or when you press button reset to give you message it is erased. As i am learning about PHP i am trying to do some project but i can not figure it out.

```
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];

    $submit="Your name and last name is input in!";
    echo $submit;
}
if(isset($_POST['reset'])){
    echo "Yours data are erased!";
}
?>

<h2>Login Page</h2>
<p>Please input your info in form bellow:</p>
    <form name="login" method="post" action="index.php">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
            <td>Name: </td>
                <td><input type="text" name="name" size="20" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Last Name: </td>
                <td><input type="password" name="lastName" size="20" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit" />
        <input type="reset" name="resetButton" value="Reset" />
    </form>        
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is no php script only java script

Comment: @Ronin, What problem are you facing exactly?

Comment: Hello, well i want it to echo on screen message after user inputs data that is successful or not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){` into `if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){`

and change reset in to `<input type="submit" name="resetButton" value="Reset" />` and call this also by the name `resetButton`

If i where you i would check `if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){` for entres because pressing submitButton will echo your message eather.

*Checkin for entry*

```
if(isset($_POST['submitButton'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];
    if (!empty($name) && !empty($lastName)) {
        $submit="Your name and last name is input in!";
        echo $submit;
    } else {
        echo 'Show this line that there is not entery in $name or $lastName';
    }
}
```

Comment: which data base are you using. and what are the fields

Comment: I am not using data base for now, i just want putting data in HTML form to reflect on page is it input and when is reset. That is for now as i am just learning PHP.

Comment: Thank you user3706324, your suggestion have resolve my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Scripts must be processed by the PHP interpreter.

On windows, a common and easy solution is to use Apache through a [WAMP setup](http://www.wampserver.com/en/).

Instructions can be found [here](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/WampServer_HowTo.html)